# Pass selected data back from Html.DropDownListFor and call contructor action

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

in my view page i placed Html.DropDownListFor, it will be used to filter data. In view i am filling it from Model as following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.Projects, New SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Nazwa"), "Select project", New With {.class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"})
```

The problem is i have no idea how to after user select something get this id from DropDown and pass back to controller Index action?

This is my controller:

```
Function Index(Optional projectid As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
        If Not IsNothing(Session("LogedUserId")) Then
            Dim userId As Integer = Session("LogedUserId")

            Dim projectsAndTransportsLists As New CustomModelProjetsTransports

            Dim transportsPerUser As New List(Of tbTransport)
            Dim ProjectsPerUser As New List(Of tbProjekt)

            If projectid = 0 Then


            Else
                transportsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbTransport)("SELECT * FROM [general].[dbo].[tbTransport] WHERE ProjectId IN " _
                                                                         & " (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [general].[dbo].[tbUserProject] " _
                                                                         & "WHERE UserId = " & Session("LogedUserId") & ") And ProjectId = 10074").ToList


                ProjectsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbProjekt)("SELECT * FROM [general].[dbo].[tbProjekt] where Id IN" _
                                                                     & "(SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [general].[dbo].[tbUserProject] WHERE UserId = " & Session("LogedUserId") & ")").ToList
            End If

            projectsAndTransportsLists.Projects = ProjectsPerUser
            projectsAndTransportsLists.Transports = transportsPerUser

            Return View(projectsAndTransportsLists)

        Else
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")
        End If
    End Function
```

**EDIT:**

I tried also to add this staff but still not working:

additional action method:

```
 <HttpPost()> _
   <ActionName("Index")> _
    Public Function IndexPost(fcii As FormCollection, Optional projectid As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
        Dim Fltcode = fcii("Id")
        Return View()

    End Function
```

and in View:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Transport", FormMethod.Post))
    @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@
    @*@<p>Your Name : @Html.TextBox("Name") </p>*@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.Projects, New SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Nazwa"), "Select project", New With {.class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"})
    @<input type="submit" value="Id" />
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally i found solution, but not sure if this is the best way - can anyone just give some advice whether its ok approach or not? I solve this that way:

```
@ModelType woitgroup_transport.CustomModelProjetsTransports


        @Using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Transport", FormMethod.Post))
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.Projects, New SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Nazwa"), "Select project", New With {.class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"})   
        @<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> Select
    </button>
```

Then in controller i created additional action with Post:

```
'This below will catch value back from View

<HttpPost()> _
       <ActionName("Index")> _
        Public Function IndexPost(fc As FormCollection) As ActionResult
                If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
                    If IsNumeric(fc(0)) Then
                        Dim ass As Integer = fc(0)    'Project id
                    End If
                End If
                Return View()
            End Function



     Public Function Index() As ActionResult

            If Not IsNothing(Session("LogedUserId")) Then
                Dim userId As Integer = Session("LogedUserId")
                Dim projectsAndTransportsLists As New CustomModelProjetsTransports

    If Not IsNothing(Session("LogedUserId")) Then

                    Dim ProjectsPerUser As New List(Of tbProjekt)
                    ProjectsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbProjekt)("SELECT * FROM [16281468_general].[dbo].[tbProjekt] WHERE Id " _
                                                                        & "IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [16281468_general].[dbo].[tbUserProject] WHERE UserId = " & Session("LogedUserId") & ")").ToList



                    If ProjectsPerUser.Count >= 0 Then
                        projectsAndTransportsLists.Projects = ProjectsPerUser
                        projectsAndTransportsLists.Transports = New List(Of tbTransport)
                        Return View(projectsAndTransportsLists)
                    Else
                        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")
                    End If


                End If

                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")

            Else
                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")
            End If
        End Function
```

My model class:

```
Public Class CustomModelProjetsTransports
    Public Projects As IEnumerable(Of woitgroup_transport.tbProjekt)
    Public Transports As IEnumerable(Of woitgroup_transport.tbTransport)
End Class
```

Is there any other better way than this one?

Comment: You cannot bind a `DropDownListFor` to a collection of complex objects. You need a property to bind to e.g. `int SelectedProject` and you should be posting back your model (not using `FormCollection`). You seem to be using hacks to fight against the MVC framework. Suggest you do to the MVC site and work through the tutorials. _Is it ok approach or not?_ - Absolutely NOT

Comment: can you please show my based on my example how should i transform this to correct MVC approach? I added more code you to look

Comment: I have long since forgotten VB, but you should have a view model with properties `int SelectedProject` and `SelectList ProjectList`. In the GET method, initialize your view model and set the value of `ProjectList`. Then in the view its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.SelectedProject, Model.ProjectList, "Select project", New With {.class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"})` and then the POST method is `Public Function IndexPost(model As yourViewModel) As ActionResult`. The value of `model.SelectedProject` will contain the ID of the selected project.